# errors when I try to return a list

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, roguelike

Now I *improved* the code a bit, cut something off it, etc.
Here is the source code:

```
import Prelude


{-- DEFINE THE TYPES --}
data Tile = Tile  -- the tiles of the map
    {char :: Char
    ,isBlocking :: Bool
    ,position :: (Int,Int)}

type Dungeon = [Tile]  -- the dungeon


{-- THE MAIN FUNCTION --}
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let theDungeon :: Dungeon
        theDungeon = mkDungeon 0 0 []
    writeFile "./test.log" $ show theDungeon


{-- DEFINE THE SIZE OF THE MAP --}
screenX = 80
screenY = 24

mapX = screenX
mapY = screenY - 4

{-- THE FUNCTIONS FOR THE DUNGEON --}
mkDungeon :: Int -> Int -> Dungeon -> Dungeon -- function for generating the dungeon
mkDungeon x y dungeon =
    if x > mapX  -- looks if the line isn't too long
        then mkDungeon 0 (y + 1) dungeon  -- it's too long, so make the next line
        else if y == 0  -- if it at the top
            then mkDungeon (x + 1) y $ dungeon ++ [Tile '#' True (x, y)}
            else if y > 0 && y < mapY  -- looks if the line is in the middle
                then if x == 0 || x == mapX  -- is it at the right or at the left
                    then mkDungeon (x + 1) y $ dungeon ++ [Tile '#' True (x, y)]
                    else mkDungeon (x + 1) y $ dungeon ++ Tile '.' False (x, y)]
                else if y == mapX  -- looks if it is at the bottom
                    then do mkDungeon (x + 1) y  $ dungeon ++ [Tile '#' True (x, y)]
                    else return $ dungeon :: Dungeon
```

So now, when I try try to compile it, I become this error:

```
main.hs:42:26:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Tile]’ with ‘Tile’
    Expected type: Dungeon
      Actual type: [Dungeon]
    In the expression: return $ dungeon :: Dungeon
    In the expression:
    ...
```

As I understand it, it trys to return a list of a list but it don't cause off:

```
mkDungeon :: Int -> Int -> Dungeon -> Dungeon
```

But if I write

```
else return $ dungeon
```

instead, I get this error:

```
main.hs:42:26:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Tile]’ with ‘Tile’
    Expected type: Dungeon
      Actual type: [Dungeon]
    In the expression: return $ dungeon
    ...
```

When I write it without `$`, I get this:

```
main.hs:42:26:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Tile]’ with ‘Tile’
    Expected type: Tile
      Actual type: Dungeon
    In the expression: return dungeon
    ...
```

So how can I return it as type Dungeon?

Comment: `do dungeon : Tile ....` looks weird, since `dungeon` has not a list type. If you are trying to modify the value of `dungeon`, know you can't do that. All those `do`s and the final `return` look wrong to me...

Comment: As an aside, I think your mkDungeon function would be much more readable using guards instead of the long nested `if` statements.

Comment: @Free_D Good idea. I'll rewrite it soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So another answer already explained that you need to use `let x = ...` for normal values, and only use `x <- ...` for monadic actions. So that's one of your problems.

---

You also don't need all those `do` blocks in `mkDungeon`. Rather than

```
then do 
  dungeon : Tile '#' True (x,y)
  mkDungeon (x + 1) y
```

you want something like

```
then mkDungeon (x + 1) y (dungeon : Tile '#' True (x,y))
```

In other words, *pass* the new dungeon to a recursive call to `mkDungeon`. But of course, this is the wrong way round: the new tile should be to the *left* of the `(:)` operator, not the right.

```
then mkDungeon (x + 1) y (Tile '#' True (x,y) : dungeon)
```

---

The next problem is that you have

```
data Dungeon = Dungeon [Tile]
```

That means that if `x`, `y` and `z` are `Tile` values, then

```
Dungeon [x, y, z]
```

is a `Dungeon` value, however

```
[x, y, z]
```

by itself is not. Your type signature for `mkDungeon` claims it takes a `Dungeon` and returns another `Dungeon`, but in fact it seems to be trying to take a list of tiles and return another list of tiles.

There are two ways to fix this. One is to make `Dungeon` a mere type alias rather than a whole new type:

```
type Dungeon = [Tile]
```

Now `Dungeon` and `[Tile]` are interchangeable, one merely being an alias to the other. Alternatively, you need to insert `Dungeon` all over the place:

```
mkDungeon x y (Dungeon ts) = ...
   ...then mkDungeon (x + y) y (Dungeon (Tile '#' True (x,y) : ts))
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I have wrote this in the code and now I only have some problems with `(:)`

Answer (score 2):

```
main = do
    let theDungeon :: Dungeon 
    theDungeon <- mkDungeon 0 0 []
    writeFile "./test.log" $ show theDungeon
```

If we remove the syntactic sugar from this, we get:

```
main =
    let
        theDungeon :: Dungeon
    in
        mkDungeon 0 0 [] >>= \theDungeon ->
        writeFile "./test.log" $ show theDungeon
```

What the error message is complaining about is the `let` block contains a type signature for `theDungeon`, but no actual definition. The next problem would be that `mkDungeon 0 0 []` produces a value of type `Dungeon`, which is not a monad, so you can't use `>>=` (and by extension `<-`) with it.

To define `theDungeon` properly you need to use `=` instead of `<-` (`<-` is for "extracting" values from monads and it's desugared using `>>=`, `=` is used for `let` (and global) bindings) and indent it in such a way that it's still part of the `let` block. So:

```
main = do
    let theDungeon :: Dungeon 
        theDungeon = mkDungeon 0 0 []
    writeFile "./test.log" $ show theDungeon
```

Or you can skip the type signature and just write `let theDungeon = mkDungeon 0 0 []`.

Comment: Ok thanks, but now I get type errors, which are similar with the errors before.

Answer (score 0):

Since `mkDungeon` has a type signature of `mkDungeon :: Int -> Int -> Dungeon -> Dungeon`, and `Dungeon` is the equivilent to `[Tile]`, this function is in the list monad.

`return` is a function defined for monads which lifts a value into monad you are using.  `return` for lists is defined as

```
return :: a -> [a]
return x = [x]
```

So since `dungeon` has type `Dungeon`, when you pass it to `return` you get `[dungeon]`.  This is not what you want and does not match the type signature which is why you get the error.

You do not need to use return at all in this case, removing it should solve your problem.  Just remember the return in Haskell is nothing like return in imperative languages; it is not used leave functions.

Comment: I know that and I only wanted that the output of the function is the dungeon. But I found a better way

Answer (score 0):

I solved It.
As you can see it in the [code](https://github.com/caffeinated-fox/epsilon/blob/AlgorithmDungeon/src/Things/MkDungeon.hs)
I have solved it by making:

```
... $ dungeon ++ [Tile ...]
```

Thanks too all of you! It helped a lot :D.